# Reactor - doOnError stops exception propagation

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this simple code

```
fun method(): Mono<String> {
    return Mono.error(RuntimeException("RUNTIME EXCEPTION"))
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    try {
        method()
            .doOnError {
                when(it){
                    is RuntimeException -> println("DO_ON_NEXT RUNTIME EXCEPTION")
                    else -> println("DO_ON_NEXT OTHER EXCEPTION")
                }
            }
            .subscribe {
                println("FLOW FINISHED")
            }
    } catch (e: Exception){
        println("CAUGHT EXCEPTION IN TRY CATCH CLAUSE")
    }
}
```

When I run it it finishes with exit code 0 but the phrase `FLOW FINISHED` from the `subscribe` clause is NOT printed.

However when I remove the `doOnError` clause, the `RuntimeException` is being caught in the try-catch and `CAUGHT EXCEPTION IN TRY CATCH CLAUSE` is printed.

Can anyone help me how to make it so that the exception will be caught in the try-catch and the `doOnError` clause will be kept ?

Comment: When I remove `doOnError` then the `CAUGHT EXCEPTION IN TRY CATCH CLAUSE` is still NOT printed and I don't see any reason why it should. Try-catch blocks don't play well together with reactive. You should rather use error handling operators provided by Reactor.